# I can't connect to internet via ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless

I have asus s551 l and i installed ubuntu beside my windows 8.1
But I have a big problem.
I can't connect to internet via ubuntu 14.04
I click on the network icon at right top of the screen but it doesn't have anything about wireles network.
and also when I start my laptop with ubuntu the tiny light in the laptob that shows the wifi and bluetooth connectivity is off.
what should I do ?
I can't use Ubuntu without internet.
thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: rfkill list all and also: iwconfig and also: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: when i type iwconfig in terminal commands ubuntu can not find wlan0. what should i do?

Comment: Please post the other results. Your wireless probably doesn't have a driver.

Comment: The results of rfkill list command"

Comment: 0: asus-wlan : Wireless LAn
  soft blocked : no
  hard blocked : no
1: asus-bluetooth : Bluetooth

Comment: The results of rfkill list command :
0: asus-wlan: Wireless Lan
Soft blocked : no
Hard blocked : no
1: asus-bluetooth : Bluetooth
Soft blocked : no
Hard blocked : no
The results of iw config command :
Eth0 no wireless extensions.
L0 no wireless extensions.
The results of lspci –nn | grep 0280
03:00.0 Network controller [0280] : MEDIATECH  Crop. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adaptor [74c3:7630]
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please get a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethered or however is available. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/mt7630.git
cd mt7630
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rt2800pci
```

Your wireless should now be working.

If it does not work as expected, check. Are there any informative clues shown in the message log?

```
sudo modprobe rt2800pci
dmesg | grep rt2
```

Is this a laptop with a wireless switch or key combination? Is it set to enable wireless?

```
rfkill list all
```

Let's do some additional troubleshooting. Reboot and open a terminal and run:

```
sudo modprobe rt2800pci
rfkill list all > wifi.txt
dmesg >> wifi.txt
iwconfig  >>  wifi.txt
modinfo rt2800pci >>  wifi.txt
```

Find the file *wifi.txt* in your user directory and copy and paste it here: http://paste.ubuntu.com Give us the link in your reply.

EDIT: The version of rt2800pci in your pastebin is not the version that includes your 7630 device. If you have had an update to the linux image, re-compile:

```
cd ~/mt7630
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r rt2800pci && sudo modprobe rt2800pci
```

Is it working now?

Comment: when i type the second line it says that:
the program 'git' is currently not installed. you can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install git
but when i type this command it says:
unable to locate package git

Comment: Please see my edit above and try again.

Comment: I did every thing as same as you said and finally I'm not connected to internet via wireless.

Comment: Please recheck: lspci -nn | grep 0280. Is your device [74c3:7630] or is it [14c3:7630]? Thanks.

Comment: it is [14c3:7630]

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: my laptop has switch to enable wireless. but it doesn't work in ubuntu.
these are the results of rfkill list all command when i write it:
0- asus-wlan : Wireless lan
soft blocked: no
hard nlocked: no
1- asus-bluetooth : Bluetooth
soft blocked: no
hard blocked: no

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: this is the link

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8961195/

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: no. it is not working yet

Comment: Please let me see another paste as above.